# NodeJs with Visual Studio not launching browser

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2013, npm

I am working on a node js application created using visual studio. Earlier I used verson 6 of node js and I was able to debug the code(the browser used to come up while debugging the app). Recently the browser stopped to launch when I debug the app. Someone suggested to update node and I did the same. Now, I have version 8 of node js but the problem still remains. I also get DeprecationWarning: 'node--debug' and 'node--debug--brk' are ivalid message when I debug the app and the browser doesn't come up as well. I can run without debugging though. How can this be fixed?